# NMF factorization to get the desired matrix

Tags: optimization, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, image-processing, nonnegative-matrices

I am working on an encryption algorithm for images, and am stuck in the following factorization.

Let $A$ be a  positive, invertible, non-sparse random matrix. Let $S$ be my image matrix that is scaled such that all entries are less than $1$. I multiply $A$ and $S$ to get $Y$ and then proceed with some algorithm.
Finally, after after decryption, I get matrix $V$.

Given $Y$, how can I get my $S$? Or, how can i get as close as possible to $S$?

I have used non-negative factorization but that is not unique and it is not giving right results. Can somebody suggest some technique to approximate $S$ given $V$?

Comment: $Y=AS$ originally

Comment: Suppose the matrices are in fact scalars, and suppose it is given that $Y=10$. What $S$ do you expect?

Comment: i understand that there are many solutions but can i get close to my $S$

Comment: If you can't say which $S$ you are looking for in the scalar case, do not expect a magic formula to solve your problem.